# Local Storage Input Name and Display Greeting for a Game

Tags: javascript, submit, storage, local

I seem to be making an error with my local storage and retrieving a response. The coin toss aspect works perfectly. I want the user to enter their name, have their named be stored as local storage and when submit is pressed the page displays a greeting using their name. My assignment requires this be done as local storage. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Heads or Tails</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
What is your name: <input type="text" class="instructions" />
<input type="text" id="name" style="display: none;" />
<button type="button" class="submit" onclick="greeting();" >Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="hello"></div>
    <h1>Will it be heads or tails?</h1>
    <input type="button" class="button" onclick="junction();" value="Let's 
      Flip!">
    <h3 id="response"></h3>

</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>


/* 
Generate randomly 1 or 2
assign 1 to heads
use if else statement
else (number is 2) assign to tails
track results
make button clickable multiple times without refresh

*/

/* Heads or tails*/
function junction(){
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;

if(randomNumber == 1){
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Heads!";
} else {
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Tails!";
}
}

/*local storage of name*/
function greeting(){
var name= getElementById('name').value;
localStorage.setItem("userName", "name");
document.write.innerText = "Hello," + localStorage.getItem('userName')+ 
"let's play heads or tails!";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing a value of name, but mistakenly you are passing it as a string, instead of the pre-defined variable that you have, because`localStorage.setItem("THE_NAME_OF_THE_SAVED_ITEM", THE_VALUE)` So, this should do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Heads or Tails</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <form>
      <!-- Few changes made here. -->
      <label for="name">What is your name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter name here...">
      <button type="button" class="submit" onclick="greeting();" >Submit</button>
</form>
<h3 id="greetUser"></h3>
<div class="hello"></div>
    <h1>Will it be heads or tails?</h1>
    <input type="button" class="button" onclick="junction();" value="Let's 
      Flip!">
    <h3 id="response"></h3>

</body>
<script>
/* 
Generate randomly 1 or 2
assign 1 to heads
use if else statement
else (number is 2) assign to tails
track results
make button clickable multiple times without refresh

*/

/* Heads or tails*/
function junction(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;

  if(randomNumber == 1){
  document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Heads!";
  } else {
  document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Tails!";
  }
}


/*local storage of name*/
function greeting(){
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var greetUser = document.getElementById("greetUser");
  // Just get rid of the "" at the value (change "name" to name).
  localStorage.setItem("userName", name);
  greetUser.textContent = "Hello," + localStorage.getItem('userName') + 
  " . Let's play heads or tails!";
}
</script>
</html>
```

Also, not entirely sure where you want to display the message from `document.write.innerText = "Hello," + localStorage.getItem('userName')+ 
"let's play heads or tails!";` but for me, when I tried that part in the dev tools, it just console logged, so look for in the console.

Comment: Nothing happens when submit is pressed, is there something wrong with my onclick in the HTML?

Comment: @Blen6035 I updated my answer, try copy-pasting it, see if it works now. I think there was a mistake with the input field.

Comment: Still nothing darn it!

Comment: You had a typo,at the greeting function, instead of `document.getElementById` you had `getElementById`.... Fixed it now in the answer

Comment: And as I said, `document.write.innerText` doesn't really gives me an output. So if you'd could instead of that, do `alert("Hello," + localStorage.getItem('userName')+ 
"let's play heads or tails!"), or have that be outputted in some element.

Comment: To answer your question I am hoping to have the message display below the submit field but now that I am looking at it I doubt I want to do .innertext? Ugg I figured I would have a silly error but the submit is still not working on my end and I am not seeing it in the console either.

Comment: It is working on my end. I am doing one more last edit, just copy-paste the whole thing into your `index.html` and it works. Tested it. You are probably not including the javascript code in the `app.js` that you have, you rather copy pasted it with out transfering the code to the actual script file. Now after the edit, just copy-paste the whole thing into your `**index.html**` file, and it will work.

Comment: Perfect! You are a life saver!

Comment: Any thoughts on how to keep the name from disappearing when the page refreshes?

Comment: Well, you could make it so when the page loads, it reads up the data from the local storage, and sets it at the `greetUser` element, just like we did at the `greeting` function, just this time on page load. That greeting part will still be updated later on when the user clicks submit btn and that will be saved for and displayed on next page refresh.